# OpenMP not waiting all threads finish before end C program

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have the following problem: My C program must count the number of occurrences of a list of words in a text file.

I use OpenMP for this, and the program, in theory, has the correct logic. When I put some `printfs` inside a `For Loop` the result of the program is correct and always the same.

When I remove `printfs` the result is incorrect, and with each execution its value changes. Given this scenario I think the reason is related to the execution time. With `printfs` the execution time is increased, so there is time to finish counting all threads and the program to work correctly. Without `prinfts`, the execution time decreases exponentially (0.000893 ms), leaving no time to finish all threads / calculations and for this reason the program prints a different result for each execution.

The parallelized code is as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(threadNumber) private(word, wordExists) shared(keyWordsOcurrences)
          for (line = 0; line < NUM_LINES; line++)
            {
                // divides the line into words separated by space
                word = strtok(lines[line], " ");
                while (word != NULL)
                {
                    // checks if the word being read is one of the monitored words
                    wordExists = checkWordOcurrences(word);
                    if (wordExists)
                    {
                        #pragma omp critical
                        keyWordsOcurrences[wordExists - 1] += 1;
                    }
                    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
            }
```

The checkWordOcurrences function called is where I put the printf responsible to make my code work properly in every execution (increasing execution time).

```
int checkWordOcurrences(char *word)
{
    int res = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < QTD_WORDS; i++)
    {
        // **this is the almighty Printf that makes everything work properly, and without it things stop working :(**
        printf("palavra %d %s - palavra 2 %s \n", i, keyWords[i], word);
        // compares current word with monitored words
        if (!strcmp(keyWords[i], word))
        {
            // if it's monitored word, returns its index (+1 because the first word has index 0 and the return type is checked as true or false)
            res = i + 1;
        }
    }

    // returns word index or 0, if current word is not monitored
    return res;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what may be happening and / or how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implicit barrier at the end of the OpenMP `for` construct and at the end of each parallel region, so it is not possible for the program to finish before all the threads have finished their assigned work.

The problem is most likely caused by the use of `strtok`. It is not a thread-safe function since the position of the search point is stored internally in the C library. When one thread is in the middle of tokenising something and another thread calls `strtok(lines[line], " ");`, this overwrites the pointer to the string being searched and now all other threads calling `strtok(NULL, " ");` are tokenising the newly set string instead of the string they were in the middle of tokenising before. It is a classical case of data race.

The solution is to use `strtok_r` instead.

```c
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(threadNumber) private(word, wordExists) shared(keyWordsOcurrences)
          for (line = 0; line < NUM_LINES; line++)
            {
                char *saveptr;
                // divides the line into words separated by space
                word = strtok_r(lines[line], " ", &saveptr);
                while (word != NULL)
                {
                    // checks if the word being read is one of the monitored words
                    wordExists = checkWordOcurrences(word);
                    if (wordExists)
                    {
                        #pragma omp critical
                        keyWordsOcurrences[wordExists - 1] += 1;
                    }
                    word = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
                }
            }
```

On a separate account, `critical` is a very heavyweight synchronisation construct implemented with locks. Simple increments such as `keyWordsOcurrences[wordExists - 1] += 1;` can be protected with atomic updates instead, which are way quicker:

```c
if (wordExists)
{
    #pragma omp atomic update
    keyWordsOcurrences[wordExists - 1] += 1;
}
```

If `QTD_WORDS` isn't a very large number, you may also use array reduction:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(threadNumber) \
                         private(word, wordExists) \
                         reduction(+:keyWordsOcurrences[0:QTD_WORDS])
          for (line = 0; line < NUM_LINES; line++)
            {
                char *saveptr;
                // divides the line into words separated by space
                word = strtok_r(lines[line], " ", &saveptr);
                while (word != NULL)
                {
                    // checks if the word being read is one of the monitored words
                    wordExists = checkWordOcurrences(word);
                    if (wordExists)
                    {
                        keyWordsOcurrences[wordExists - 1] += 1;
                    }
                    word = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
                }
            }
```

Array reduction for C and C++ is a relatively new OpenMP feature though and requires a compiler that supports OpenMP 4.5. It is possible to do it by hand for older compilers, but that goes way out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: As a suggestion of an improvement, would be to remove that critical, for either a finer grain lock, or using data replication.

Comment: @dreamcrash I hesitated to do so earlier because it goes out of the scope of the original question and introduces concepts that people often try to apply in the wrong cases.

Comment: Yep, you are actually, right, however the answer now looks perfect.

Comment: Thank you sir, your solution worked and I fully understood what was I doing wrong by reading your answer.